# Increment/Decrement timings

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime, increment

I need to increment/decrement the timings in PostgreSQL database.

Below is the output for the table containing the column type as **"timestamp without time zone"**

I need to change the date as well if only time goes above 24 hours. Please assist

```
select start_time from XXXXX;

    "2017-05-15 15:08:54.639"
    "2017-05-10 17:30:25.056"
    "2017-05-10 17:35:35.418"
    "2017-05-11 15:05:40.071"
    "2017-05-11 18:11:51.431"
    "2017-05-18 11:15:00"
    "2017-05-11 15:07:43.534"
    "2017-05-11 15:10:15.808"
    "2017-05-11 15:15:24.847"
    "2017-05-15 17:39:00"
```

If i increment 1 hour, the sample output should be as below

```
   "2017-05-15 16:08:54.639"
    "2017-05-10 18:30:25.056"
    "2017-05-10 18:35:35.418"
    "2017-05-11 16:05:40.071"
    "2017-05-11 19:11:51.431"
    "2017-05-18 12:15:00"
    "2017-05-11 16:07:43.534"
    "2017-05-11 16:10:15.808"
    "2017-05-11 16:15:24.847"
    "2017-05-15 18:39:00"
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: Thanks, Added the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. While executing the query "select start_time + interval '1' from XXXX"  produces the same results, there is no change on the result set.

Comment: you skipped `hour` - please try exactly what @a_horse_with_no_name suggested or `select start_time + '1 hour'::interval`

Comment: Many thanks. It works as expected by using the query "select start_time + interval '1 hours 20 minutes 10 seconds' from XXXXX". Voted for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an [interval of 1 hour](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to the value:

```
select start_time + interval '1' hour
from ...
```